# how to send a facebook friend request ( not a application friend request ) from android application?

Tags: android, facebook

how to send a Facebook friend request ( not a application friend request ) from android application?

I have the profile information of other friend like profile id, name, email id...

Is it possible to send friend request through android application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you CAN send friend requests from your Android app.Everything you need is [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/send-requests/).Everything is done using the Facebook APIs.I assume you are already working with this?

Comment: It sends the request, those who are all already present in the Facebook friend list. for example  I want to send friend request to your Facebook id(unknown friend), I have your Facebook profile information, in this case it is possible?

Comment: Of course, isn't that the general idea? to send a request to someone who isn't on your friend list? Once you implement the functionality into your app, there is a search function where you can type the name of the person you want to add and then Facebook displays the person's name and picture then you can select the person you want.Read the link i sent you.I promise you will understand.You don't even need to worry about writing the code.All you need to worry about is wiring Facebook to your app.